# Docker starts the springboot project and reports java version error

Tags: java, docker

I use the following dockerfile to generate a image call userservice

```
FROM java:8-alpine
COPY ./userservice.jar /tmp/userservice.jar
ENTRYPOINT java -jar /tmp/userservice.jar
```

then I use the following command to run container

> docker run --name userservice_container userservice

But the terminal prompts that the java version does not match，as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/imortal/UserApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
```

So I went to check the compiled bytecode version, it is indeed 52, I don’t know why this error is still reported

```
javap -verbose .\UserApplication.class
public class com.imortal.UserApplication
minor version: 0
major version: 52
flags: (0x0021) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
this_class: #2                          // 
com/imortal/UserApplication
super_class: #4                         // java/lang/Object
interfaces: 0, fields: 0, methods: 2, attributes: 2
```

Comment: Did you use any kind of CI/CD for deployment? And where did you take the jar file from for the version checking? It's due to the jar file that you checked with version 52 maybe in your local development, but the CI/CD use the JDK11 to build and deploy your project.

Comment: Yes, I packaged the project into a jar in the local environment and transferred it to the server. I also re-downloaded the jar on the server to the local for decompression, and then checked that the bytecode version is still 52.

Answer (score 0):

Use a docker image that has a compatible jdk version, so that it doesn't create any conflict with all the microservices that you are having. This issue probably is occuring because one of your microservices is build on some other jdk version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but after I checked it, I confirmed that it was compiled by jdk8, and the bytecode version is 52.